# How to implement custom kafka Partition using spring cloud stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, partitioning, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to implement a custom Kafka Partitioner using spring cloud stream bindings. I would like to just custom Partition the user topic and not do anything with company topic(Kafka will use DefaultPartitioner in this case).

My bindings configuration:

```css
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        comp-out:
          destination: company
          contentType: application/json
        user-out:
          destination: user
          contentType: application/json
```

As per reference document: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.1.0.RC4/single/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_partitioning_with_the_kafka_binder
I modified the configuration to this:

```css
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        comp-out:
          destination: company
          contentType: application/json
        user-out:
          destination: user
          contentType: application/json
        producer:
            partitioned: true
            partitionSelectorClass: config.UserPartitioner
```

I Post the message into Stream using this:

```js
public void postUserStream(User user) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            LOG.info("Posting User {} into Kafka stream...", user);
            MessageChannel messageChannel = messageStreams.outboundUser();
            messageChannel
                    .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(user)
                            .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Error while populating User stream into Kafka.. ", ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

My UserPartitioner Class:

```js
public class UserPartitioner extends DefaultPartitioner {
    @Override
    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes,
          Cluster cluster) {

        String partitionKey = null;
        if (Objects.nonNull(value)) {
            User user = (User) value;
            partitionKey = String.valueOf(user.getCompanyId()) + "_" + String.valueOf(user.getId());
            keyBytes = partitionKey.getBytes();
        }
        return super.partition(topic, partitionKey, keyBytes, value, valueBytes, cluster);
    }
}
```

I end up receiving following exception:

Description:
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.stream.bindings.user-out.producer' to org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.ProducerProperties:

```
Property: spring.cloud.stream.bindings.user-out.producer.partitioned
Value: true
Origin: "spring.cloud.stream.bindings.user-out.producer.partitioned" from property source "bootstrapProperties"
Reason: No setter found for property: partitioned
```

Action:
Update your application's configuration

Any reference link on how to set up Custom Partition using message binders will be helpful.

Edit: Based on the documentation Tried the below steps as well:

user-out:
          destination: user
          contentType: application/json
          producer:
           partitionKeyExtractorClass: config.SimpleUserPartitioner

```js
@Component
public class SimpleUserPartitioner implements PartitionKeyExtractorStrategy {

 @Override
 public Object extractKey(Message<?> message) {
  if(message.getPayload() instanceof BaseUser) {
   BaseUser user = (BaseUser) message.getPayload();
   return user.getId();
  }
  return 10;
 }
    
}
```

update 2: Solution that worked for me add partitioncount to bindings and autoaddpartitions to true in binder:

```css
spring:
  logging:
    level: info
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        user-out:
          destination: user
          contentType: application/json
          producer:
            partition-key-expression: headers['partitionKey']
            partition-count: 4
```

```css
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
          autoAddPartitions: true
```

Comment: Are your message keys just null? Couldn't you put `user.getCompanyId()) + "_" + String.valueOf(user.getId()` as the key when you build a message? Then you don't need a custom partitioner

Answer (score 2):

There is no property `partitioned`; the getter depends on other properties...

```
public boolean isPartitioned() {
    return this.partitionKeyExpression != null
            || this.partitionKeyExtractorName != null;
}

partitionSelectorClass: config.UserPartitioner
```

The `UserPartitioner` is a Kafka `Partitioner` - it determines which consumers get which partitions (on the consumer side)

The `partitionSelectorClass` has to be a `PartitionSelectorStrategy` - it determines which partition a record is **sent to** (on the producer side).

These are completely different objects.

If you **really** want to customize the way partitions are distributed across consumer instances, that is a Kafka concern and has nothing to do with Spring.

Furthermore, all consumer bindings in the same binder will use the same `Partitioner`. You would have to configure multiple binders to have different `Partitioner`s.

Given your question, I think you are simply confusing `Partitioner` with `PartitionSelectorStrategy` and you need the latter.

Comment: Gary Thank you very much for your reply. I guess i have not phrased my question properly. I would like to know how to configure kafka to use my customPartionClass instead of its defaultPartion Strategy through spring cloud. From your comment one thing is clear that i will have to have multiple binders if i have a different Partitioning strategy for bindings. Is there any example that you can point me to? Also like you mentioned i would like to know where i can configure this PartitionSelectorStrategy.

Comment: See [the documentation for how to set arbitrary kafka properties](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties) `spring,cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.user-in.consumer.configuration.partitioner.class=config.UserPartitioner`. Also [see the documentation about configuring multiple binders](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-systems). To select partitions use the `partitionSelectorClass` with a custom `PartitionSelectorStrategy`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs.I tried this spring,cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.user-in.consumer.configuration.partitioner.class=config.UserPartitioner and the user partition partitions the message by userId. But when i do this at consumer - @StreamListener(MessageStreams.INPUT)
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false)
    public void handleUser(@Payload BaseUser user, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) Long recpartitionId
      ) {} i see that the receivedPartitionId is always 0. Is there a way for me to check if I am configuring it properly?

Comment: Also i followed the documentation and tried to extract the Partition key by implementing : PartitionKeyExtractorStrategy and then added this to my configuration. Please see my updated post for this. Even then I am seeing the PartitionId as 0.

Comment: Use a debugger to make sure your partition key strategy is properly configured. Also turn on DEBUG logging; you should see the `scst_partition` message header set to the requested partition.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your inputs.It was a mistake from my side that i missed partitioncount and autoaddPartition while configuring the bindings and binders respectively. After i made this change, the Partition works fine. Thanks once again for your time and inputs. I will update the post with working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Also, note; The `partitionSelectorClass` . has been deprecated for a while now and have been removed in the current master (won't be available in 3.0.0) in favor of `partitionSelectorName` - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.0.M1/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-partitioning

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your inputs.I have not upgraded to 3.0.0 yet  but will keep this in mind when we upgrade.